# Using limit conditions to find a function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I have a series of limits for a function and I was wondering what the best way would  be to find the original function. I do know the answer but not sure what the best ways of going about finding the function is.

$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)= -\infty$$ $$\lim_{x\to ±\infty}f(x)=0$$ $$\lim_{x\to 3^-}f(x)=\infty$$ $$\lim_{x\to 3^+}f(x)=-\infty$$

And finally $f(2)=0$. If it helps I can give the answer below but I shouldn't technically have it!

My first ideas were that the top must be $(2-x)$ as $f(2)=0$, but I am not sure about the denominator!

Thank you!

Hint: The function is $$f(x)=\frac{2-x}{x^2(x-3)}$$

Comment: I have put the function in the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after a rational function $\dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$, then you need to have $\deg P(x)<\deg Q(x)$, so that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=0$. Since $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to3^-}f(x)=\infty$, $f$ will have to have a zero between $0$ and $3$ and you want to have $2$ as one such zero. And, since you want to have $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=-\infty$, it would be good if it behaved like $\dfrac{-1}{x^2}$ there. Also, you want it to behave like $\dfrac{-1}{x-3}$ near $3$. So, take$$f(x)=-\frac{x-2}{x^2(x-3)}.$$

Comment: This looks good, also $f(2)=0$ so maybe numerator should be $(2-x)$? Otherwise thank you!

Comment: I forgot the condition $f(2)=0$! I shall edit my answer.